# Is there a way to detect that SMS text messages have been deleted, or is there a text message deletion history?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, sms, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4, delete

I don't know if this is possible, but is there a way to detect that SMS text messages were deleted on an android phone, specifically the Samsung Galaxy S4 phone, Android OS 4.2?  I'm not looking to find the content of deleted text messages.  I'm curious if you can, essentially, see a text message deletion history.  For example, you deleted 5 text messages on this day from this person.  Is this possible?  Has anyone ever heard of something like this?

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Sqlite database which is where the SMS are stored, are purged depending on *Settings* from within Messaging App, specifically *Delete Old Messages* as limit is reached which is IIRC defined by *Text Message Limit*.

Answer (score 0):

I heard a while back that all of the text messages you send get kept on your SIM card. I just did some quick research and I guess it is true:

- http://www.pimall.com/nais/phonefilepro.html
- http://hiddencameragear.com/cellphone-sim-card-file-retriever-recover-calls-texts-history-and-more

These devices will allow you to see the contents of the text messages and also the sender and receiver. If you are looking for a way to do it through your Android device, then it would be a lot more work. You would have to try to do a data recovery on your hard drive (which is a lot of messing around). Even if you did do a data recovery, the chances of you getting any of your text messages back are slim, and if you have encryption enabled forget it.

Comment: AFAIK, most newer phones nowadays no longer save text messages on the SIM card.